# Emulating physical buttons / lower level touchscreen control

Tags: android, multi-touch

One thing I find many Android games and emulators get wrong is when the user presses multiple (on-screen) buttons simultaneously. I'm wondering how one could fix that.

Imagine a game like Super Mario World. You have two buttons on the right side (simplified): Y is for running and B is for jumping. Typically, you hold Y most of the time with the tip of your thumb, and when you want to jump you lay down your thumb and press B, too.

Situations like this understandably confuse Android. Instead of detecting two presses, it just moves the one from the Y button down a bit.

What I'd need to fix this is one of the following:

- Raw touch data as a bitmap (but probably too computationally expensive, and doesn't leave the touchscreen anyway)
- The detected touch points in more detail, e.g. as best-fit ellipses or polygons
- The ability to define touch regions. If a finger overlaps such a region a certain amount, the region fires.

(The points are from low- to high level, e.g. if I had the first I could emulate the other ones.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for `TouchDelegate`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html

Comment: Seems like you can only add rectangular margins around a view with TouchDelegate? But thanks, it might be worth a look.